# Parent.Location not working within php statement

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, flash, if-statement

One of the sites I recently had to migrate servers for, has a weird issue. It was working fine at there end (on old server)

The site has a menu made in Flash (swf) & when clicked it shows the URLs such as `www.domain.com/index.php?pag=projects` & `www.domain.com/index.php?pag=about` & so on. but, the page still stays on index.php (the home page)

The index.php has statements for the queries as below

```
<?php 
if($page=='about'){
    echo "<script language='javascript'>parent.location='about.php' ;</script>"; die();
}
elseif($page=='projects'){
    echo "<script language='javascript'>parent.location='projects.php' ;</script>"; die();
}
```

And the htaccess file is as follows

```
#Force www: 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

What's missing to prevent it from redirecting to the said php files?

I don't have access to the source Flash file. 
Any help would be awesome.

TIA :)

Comment: And from where $page comes ? If you print $page do you see any of the spected values (about, projects) ?

Comment: Thanks Dayron, Will look into it. Wonder why a static swf menu is so complex when each linked page is a a static file! :)

Comment: Your `.htaccess` seems to be completely unrelated to the problem. Even if the rule would be executed, it would redirect with the original query string attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that old server has register globals enabled, so the parameter page from URL is accessible directly calling $page. Replace each $page by $_GET['page'].

Comment: Wowness! Thanks so much Dayron... I completely never looked into this possibility. Created a php.ini with `register_globals = on` & it works as desired. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
if($page=='about'){
  echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location.href='about.php' ;</script>"; 
   die();
}
elseif($page=='projects'){
 echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location.href='projects.php' ;</script>";
   die();
}
```

Comment: Hey thank Sourav, but, that's not working. Not sure what's missing. No luck yet. Anything else?